# get values from database and sort them based on other fields

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter, sorting

I'm using php and mysql -[codeigniter framework]- and this is my table structure:

[Please visit this image to find out table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdQLw.png)

Every single item is separated to three or four parts that these parts made this item's price.

And these items belong to an invoice that will point using `refid`. **`refid` is `invoice_id` in fact.**

now I need to get a specific invoice items and show them in a table.

this is what I need:

[Please visit this image to find out my need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3eMM.png)

I do not have any problem to get values from database and I will use `codeigniter active records`.

As you may know, codeigniter database `result_array` function will give us an associative array. Now I want to separate every item from other and display them in a html table and I have to use `rowspan` for every item dependence sub items.

Would you please help me to find out how should I use result array to simply show the result in a html table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so lets assume that you are getting a result array like this,

```
        $result = array(
            array(
                'id' => 26,
                'price' => 100,
                'parent' => 0
            ),
            array(
                'id' => 27,
                'price' => 100,
                'parent' => 26
            ),
            array(
                'id' => 28,
                'price' => 150,
                'parent' => 26
            ),
            array(
                'id' => 29,
                'price' => 100,
                'parent' => 26
            ),
            array(
                'id' => 30,
                'price' => 100,
                'parent' => 0
            ),
            array(
                'id' => 31,
                'price' => 99,
                'parent' => 30
            ),
            array(
                'id' => 32,
                'price' => 75,
                'parent' => 30
            ),
            array(
                'id' => 33,
                'price' => 600,
                'parent' => 0
            ),
            array(
                'id' => 34,
                'price' => 100,
                'parent' => 33
            ),
            array(
                'id' => 35,
                'price' => 50,
                'parent' => 33
            ),
            array(
                'id' => 36,
                'price' => 100,
                'parent' => 33
            ),
        );
```

i cant insert all the data manually in the array from your image, so i have inserted only the needed once,

so now u can do something like this to group the data of same item,

```
        $new_array =  array();
        $invoice_price = 0;
        foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
            $invoice_price += $value['price'];
            if($value['parent'] == 0){
                $new_array[$value['id']]['other_data'][] = $value;
                $new_array[$value['id']]['final_price'] = $value['price'];
            }else{
                $new_array[$value['parent']]['other_data'][] = $value;
                $new_array[$value['parent']]['final_price'] += $value['price'];
            }
        }
```

now if u print this $new_array, u will get the following output,

```
Array
(
    [26] => Array
        (
            [other_data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 26
                            [price] => 100
                            [parent] => 0
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 27
                            [price] => 100
                            [parent] => 26
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 28
                            [price] => 150
                            [parent] => 26
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 29
                            [price] => 100
                            [parent] => 26
                        )

                )

            [final_price] => 450
        )

    [30] => Array
        (
            [other_data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 30
                            [price] => 100
                            [parent] => 0
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 31
                            [price] => 99
                            [parent] => 30
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 32
                            [price] => 75
                            [parent] => 30
                        )

                )

            [final_price] => 274
        )

    [33] => Array
        (
            [other_data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 33
                            [price] => 600
                            [parent] => 0
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 34
                            [price] => 100
                            [parent] => 33
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 35
                            [price] => 50
                            [parent] => 33
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 36
                            [price] => 100
                            [parent] => 33
                        )

                )

            [final_price] => 850
        )

)
```

hope u can see that the data is already groups by items.
now just send the data in your view file,

```
$this->load->view('yourviewfilename',array('data'=>$new_array,'invoice_price'=>$invoice_price));
```

and to print the table like your screenshot use the following code,

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>parent</th>
        <th>price</th>
        <th>final price</th>
    </tr>
    <?php $count = 0; ?>
    <?php foreach ($data as $key => $value) { ?>
        <?php $count++; ?>
        <?php foreach ($value['other_data'] as $k => $v) { ?>
            <tr>
                <?php if ($k == 0) { ?>
                    <td rowspan="<?php echo count($value['other_data']); ?>"><?php echo $count ?></td>
                <?php } ?>
                <td> <?php echo $v['parent']; ?></td>
                <td> <?php echo $v['price']; ?></td>
                <?php if ($k == 0) { ?>
                    <td rowspan="<?php echo count($value['other_data']); ?>"><?php echo $value['final_price']; ?></td>
                <?php } ?>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>

    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

u will get output like this,

[image]

hope u got the point and can print the other data you needed.

Comment: Thanks. That was a perfect answer. Unfortunately I can't vote up but I'll do this as soon as it's possible. I need another thing. What if I want to sum all final prices to get invoice price.??

Comment: see the edited answer, while grouping the result, all prices are adding in a $invoice_price variable.  and after that while loading the view the invoice price is passed. so u can access this price by calling $invoice_price in view or controller both

Comment: @Codepen : i hope this fulfill all u needed and wont forget to vote ;-)

Comment: Yes, that's great. I won't forget as soon as my reputation grow to 15... ;-)